# Select csv rows with unique value in a particular column Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with rows such as

```
A,apple,102
A,orange,103
B,banana,101
C,peach,102
B,orange,104
```

and so on...

I want to remove rows with duplicate values in the first column, the output of the above should be:

```
A,apple,102
B,banana,101
C,peach,102
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty set and add the values of the first columns to it. If it's already in the set, just skip to the next row, eg:

```
import csv

column_values = set()
new_rows = []

with open('example.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if (row[0] in column_values):
            continue
        column_values.add(row[0])
        new_rows.append(row)

with open('updated.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools-recipes) there is a recipe for `unique_everseen` (slightly adapted here). may be a bit overkill here but it works:

```
from io import StringIO
from csv import reader
from operator import itemgetter


def unique_everseen(iterable, key):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    for element in iterable:
        k = key(element)
        if k not in seen:
            seen_add(k)
            yield element

txt = '''A,apple,102
A,orange,103
B,banana,101
C,peach,102
B,orange,104'''

with StringIO(txt) as file:
    rows = reader(file)
    unique_rows = unique_everseen(rows, key=itemgetter(0))
    for row in unique_rows:
        print(row)
```

i use [`operator.itemgetter(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as `key` in order to select the first column in your rows.

you could then write the `row`s to a new file using `csv.writer`.

of course you will have to replace `StringIO(txt)` with something like `open('file.csv', 'r')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""A,apple,102
A,orange,103
B,banana,101
C,peach,102
B,orange,104""")

# read file and drop duplicates, replace x with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(x, names=['letter', 'fruit', 'value'])\
       .drop_duplicates('fruit', keep=False)

# export to output csv
df.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False, header=False)

print(df)

  letter   fruit  value
0      A   apple    102
2      B  banana    101
3      C   peach    102
```